# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'tupledict' and 'float'

Tags: python, constraints, gurobi

I have a model to be optimized by gurobi/python interface. the model is called m.
Bk is a continuous variable and t[0,j] is a value of a key in a dictionary, why Gurobi cannot add Bk to t[0,j].

I get this error at the next constraint:

```
m.addConstrs((B[j] >= Bk + t[0,j] - M*(1-xijk[k,0,j]) for j in N for k in K), '9')
```

I set the following input data:

```
ek=0
lk = 25200
K = [1,2]
N = [ i for i in range(23)]
Xijk = m.addVars(K,N,N, vtype= GRB.BINARY) 

Bk = m.addVars(K, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS)
B  = m.addVars(N ,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS)

t = {(0, 0): 0.0, (0, 9): 0.0, (0, 1): 59.0, (0, 2): 471.0, (0, 3): 353.0, (0, 4): 529.0, (0, 5): 471.0, (0, 6): 412.0, (0, 7): 412.0, (0, 8): 412.0, (0, 10): 353.0, (0, 11): 59.0, (0, 12): 471.0 .........to (22,22):0.0}
```

Bk appears later in constraint# 16 as follows

```
m.addConstrs((Bk >= ek for k in K), '16-')
m.addConstrs((Bk <= lk for k in K), '16')
```

Comment: Please provide more details. Where is the error? What is m?

Comment: Bk is a continuous varaible and t[0,j] is a value of a key in a dictionary, why Gurobi cannot add Bk to t[0,j].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have caught the error. Since Bk is created by addVars. it is a tupldict. You typically build a tupledict by calling Model.addVars. But gurobi can't add a tupldict to a float number. Therefore I should have written Bk[k] instead of Bk.